# Sudo intermittently fails

Tags: macos, sudo

As part of my work I have to run various commands using sudo (I am a local admin on the machine).

Recently I have experienced a very strange situation where despite having previously run sudo commands during my session, it will suddenly start returning the error:
`[my username] is not in the sudoers file. This incident will be reported.` for every attempt to use sudo.

Even stranger, after a period of time, it will often start working again and allow me to run sudo commands once more. Otherwise, I have to log out and back in to fix the issue.

I have checked the Users settings panel, which still shows me as an admin.

I'm running High Sierra (10.13.3) on a Mac Pro, in case it helps.

Comment: Is the Mac Pro connected to a network with centrally managed user accounts? Can you, for example, log in to another Mac at work using the same credentials?

Comment: Yes, it's part of a company network so can log in to any machine, however the local admin rights are set on a per-machine basis (so if I logged into a colleague's machine I would not automatically have admin rights)